# How to adjust the amount of rotation programmatically in Roblox first person view?

Tags: lua, roblox

The goal is to make a espionage game, so that it starts with a third person view, and if player press F, it changes to first person view. With first person view, it's like equipped with a binocular, and it has 3 zoom levels (camera.FieldOfView).

Imagine there is a house in front of me about 100 feet away. When I am in first person view, I want to click key V to change field of view. I will have 3 levels: 50 degrees, 30 degrees, and 10 degrees.

```
game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:connect(function (input, _)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.V then
        if player.CameraMode == Enum.CameraMode.LockFirstPerson then
            view_index = view_index + 1
            if view_index >= table.getn(all_views) then
                view_index = view_index - table.getn(all_views)
            end
            camera.FieldOfView = all_views[view_index + 1]
        end
    end
end)
```

What I found is that when I move the mouse (approximately same distance on the mouse pad), my orientation moves approximately the same amount, that is to say, it always moves across the whole house. I hoped to move only across the window if it's 30 degree field of view, and less if it's 10 degree. I want to have more subtle controls on rotation when I "Zoom in" to look at the details of an object. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `game:GetService("UserInputService")..MouseDeltaSensitivity`

```
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
UserInputService.MouseDeltaSensitivity = 0.1 -- or 1, or 0.01 for different sensitivity
```

Check this [link](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/UserInputService/MouseDeltaSensitivity)